# Plural formation in Bulgarian

Tags: morphology, plurality, morphological-analysis

How could you analyze the formation of the plural below?

**Singular - Plural** 
*teatər* - *teatri* - theater
*bobər* - *bobri* -   beaver
*pesen* - *pesni* -  song
*psalom* - *psalmi* -   psalm
*bancik* - *bancigi* -   band saw
*izverk* - *izvergi* -   monster

/i/ is the plural suffix, and vowels such as /ə,e,o/ are deleted in plurals.

Comment: Is that last sentence the rule you're proposing to make plurals? How do you state it formally?

Comment: @user3608 I have edited your question for better readability - feel free to revert the changes, if you don't agree with them.

Answer (score 6):

The deletion of certain `<e o>` and all `<ъ>` in Bulgarian is an effect of **Havlík's law**, and the forms `/bantsik::bantsigi/` and `/izverk::izvergi/` are demonstrative of Bulgarian's word-final devoicing; all Bulgarian obstruents lose voicing word-finally and the underlying forms are actually `|bantsig::bantsigi|` and `|izverg::izvergi|`

Other than that, the plural is formed with, among others, a suffix /-i/

As to answering the question, I'd just analyse the plural forms as `"word-PL"`, nothing more.

Comment: Bulgarian plurals are formed with lots of fifferent suffixes, not only `-i`, and not every `ъ` /ə/ is deleted before the plural suffix, like in /zəb :: zəbi/ (tooth :: teeth).

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me: I said that (well, at least as far as I know) all deletions of `<ъ>` are a result of Havlík's law, not that all `<ъ>` get deleted due to Havlík's law (of course some don't, but those that do do so due to Havlík's law)

Comment: You misunderstand Havlík's law. This law describes where the Proto-Slavic vowel `<ъ>` disappeared and where it became a full-length vowel, and this law stopped to work long before the word `teatər` first appeared in Slavic languages.  In `teatər`, `bobər` and `pesen` the last vowel, which gets deleted in the plural, is a Bulgarian innovation, that's a case of epenthesis (anaptyxis), no Proto-Slavic `<ъ>` corresponds to the last vowel of these words, so Havlík's law doesn't apply here, these vowels were introduced long after that law stopped working.

Comment: Well yeah, but an extension of the effect of Havlík's law - the fleeting vocalisations of most (all?) Slavic languages - is what caused this; i.e. an analogical development. The same happens in Serbian, where loanwords that have /a/ in the final syllable sometimes lose it in declension mimicking the effects of Havlík's law. Also, the law isn't a Proto-Slavic development; it's rather a development in Common Slavic as it is not present in Old Church Slavonic

Answer (score 4):

Plural formation in Bulgarian depends on whether the noun is masculine, feminine or neuter.
On top of that, it also depends if the noun is monosyllabic or polysyllabic.

1. **Masculine nouns**

   - **Monosyllabic**: in most cases, use ~ove at the end of the word (e.g. stol - stolove - chair). Nevertheless, some masculine monosyllabic nouns have their own plural form and do not use the ~ove ending (den - dni - day; krak - kraka - leg). There are different historical reason for these exceptions.
   - **Polysyllabic**: form the plural by adding ~i at the end (pisatel - pisateli - writer). Some polysyllabic masculine nouns form the plural through phonetic change. All nouns ending in ~ik change the ~k for ~tsi /~ци/ (uchenik - uchenitsi - pupil; rabotnik - rabotnitsi - workman).
2. **Feminine nouns** form the plural by adding ~i at the end. If the noun end in ~a or ~ya /я/ the ~i replaces it (sestra - sestri - sister; staya - stai - room); nouns that end in ~iya /~ия/ form the plural with ~ii (chiniya - chinii - plate)
3. **Neuter**

   - if the noun **ends in ~o**, the plural is formed by replacing the ~o with ~a (leglo - legla - bed)
   - if the noun **ends in ~e**, the plural is formed by replacing the ~e with ~a (letishte - letishta - airport)
   - Exceptions: Some neuter nouns have their own form (tsvete - tsvetya - flower; oko - ochi - eye). Again - there are different historical reasons for the formation of these words.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't really address the dropped vowels asked about in the question, such as teatər - teatri